# How to infer react props based on dynamic tag "as"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been wondering how some react ui libraries accept an "as" prop capable of inferring the dynamic tag name / component props with typescript.

Take `headless-ui` for example, if you want to use it with `framer-motion` you just have to do something like this for example:

```
<Combobox.Options as={motion.ul}>...</Combobox.Options>
```

And this component will infer not only its own properties but also the ones coming from `motion.ul` which in this case is not a string tag rather a custom component.

Any ideas?

Comment: i think you're talking about polymorphic components, try google that

Comment: @coglialoro holy s**t that's exactly what I was looking for. Never came across that name before. Thank you so much!